# Bulk update in SQLAlchemy Core using WHERE

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have managed to work with the bulk insert in SQLAlchemy like:

```
conn.execute(addresses.insert(), [ 
   {'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@yahoo.com'},
   {'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@msn.com'},
   {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'www@www.org'},
   {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'wendy@aol.com'},
])
```

What I need now is something equivalent for update. I have tried this:

```
conn.execute(addresses.insert(), [ 
   {'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@yahoo.com', 'id':12},
   {'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@msn.com', 'id':13},
   {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'www@www.org', 'id':14},
   {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'wendy@aol.com', 'id':15},
])
```

expecting that each row gets updated according to the 'id' field, but it doesn't work. I assume that it is because I have not specified a WHERE clause, but I don't know how to specify a WHERE clause using data that is included in the dictionary.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Read the [Updating and Deleting Rows with Core](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_update.html#updating-and-deleting-rows-with-core) section of the tutorial. The following code should get you started:

```
from sqlalchemy import bindparam
stmt = addresses.update().\
    where(addresses.c.id == bindparam('_id')).\
    values({
        'user_id': bindparam('user_id'),
        'email_address': bindparam('email_address'),
    })

conn.execute(stmt, [
    {'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@yahoo.com', '_id':1},
    {'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@msn.com', '_id':2},
    {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'www@www.org', '_id':3},
    {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'wendy@aol.com', '_id':4},
])
```

Comment: what about inserts that also relies on several selects?

Comment: `update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'values'`, what is addresses in this example?

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide: `addresses` in an instance of a [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table)

Comment: This is very slow.
Similarly, for inserts, I noticed that `conn.execute(table.insert().values([...]))` was much faster than `conn.execute(table.insert(), [...])`
Is there a similar thing I can do for updates to make it fast?

Comment: @nbarraille - the former statement is faster as it does “insert into table (...) values (...), (...), (...)” whereas the latter is equivalent to executemany(), which calls execute repeatedly for each row.

Comment: I think the updated link is now [_Insert, Updates, Deletes_](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#).

Comment: What if I have to bind my list of dictionaries to my `values()` ?

Comment: bindparam() refuse to use the same table name, but it is exactly what I want,Is there a way to get this?

Comment: @AndySu, what do you mean by "refuse to use the same table name"?

Comment: @van ex: `where(addresses.c.id == bindparam('_id')`  bindparam() bind key '_id' instead of 'id'.

Answer (score 34):

The session has function called `bulk_insert_mappings` and `bulk_update_mappings`: [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/persistence_techniques.html#bulk-operations).

Be aware that you have to provide primary key in mappings

```
# List of dictionary including primary key
user_mappings = [{
    'user_id': 1, # This is pk?
    'email_address': 'jack@yahoo.com',
    '_id': 1
}, ...]

session.bulk_update_mappings(User, user_mappings)
session.commit()
```

Comment: Does not work for me with a composite primary key. (v_id, order)

Comment: @NickWoodhams Worked perfectly in my case, with Composite primary key(Col1, col2). What errror were you facing?

Comment: Do note that the question requests a solution using SQLAlchemy core. This solution using the SQLAlchemy ORM, not core.

Answer (score 4):

In 2023, the SQLAlchemy 2.0 [changed the API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-bulk-update-by-primary-key):

```
from sqlalchemy import update
session.execute(
    update(User),
    [
        {"id": 1, "fullname": "Spongebob Squarepants"},
        {"id": 3, "fullname": "Patrick Star"},
        {"id": 5, "fullname": "Eugene H. Krabs"},
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 3):

@Jongbin Park's solution DID work for me with a composite primary key. (Azure SQL Server).

```
update_vals = []
update_vals.append(dict(Name='name_a', StartDate='2020-05-26 20:17:32', EndDate='2020-05-26 20:46:03', Comment='TEST COMMENT 1'))
update_vals.append(dict(Name='name_b', StartDate='2020-05-26 21:31:16', EndDate='2020-05-26 21:38:37', Comment='TEST COMMENT 2'))
s.bulk_update_mappings(MyTable, update_vals)
s.commit()
```

where Name, StartDate, and EndDate are all part of the composite pk. 'Comment' is the value to update in the db

Answer (score 0):

Using above answers did work for because sqlalchemy was claiming that you need to add **synchronize_session=None**
I have used the following code to cook the right recipe

```
values= {"id" : results.id, "user_id": results.id}
        if user.email is not None:
            values['email'] = user.email
        if user.first_name is not None:
            values['first_name'] = user.first_name

        if user.last_name is not None:
            values['last_name'] = user.last_name
        else:
            values['last_name'] = results.last_name
update_user_q = update(u).where(u.id == bindparam("user_id")).values(
                            email=bindparam("email"),
                            first_name=bindparam("first_name"), last_name=bindparam("last_name")).execution_options(
                            synchronize_session=None)
            db.execute(update_user_q, [
                values]
                )
            db.commit()
```

> Don't forget to pass the primary in your data