# calling GeomFromText and other such functions using sqlalchemy core

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am working in python with a MySQL database.  I have a table that uses the MySQL geometry extension, so I need to call the GeomFromText MySQL function during an update statement, something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET Location=GeomFromText('Point(39.0 55.0)') where id=1;
UPDATE myTable SET Location=GeomFromText('Point(39.0 55.0)') where id=2;
```

Originally, I was using the low-level MySQLdb library.  I am switching to using the SQLAlchemy core library (I cannot use the SQLAlchemy ORM for speed and other reasons).

If I were using the lower-level MySQLdb library directly, I would do something like this:

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
commandTemplate = "UPDATE myTable SET Location=GeomFromText(%s) where id=%s"
connection = mysql.connect(host="myhost",user="user",passwd="password",db="my_schema")
cursor = connection.cursor(mysql.cursors.DictCursor)
data = [
    ("Point(39.0 55.0)",1),
    ("Point(39.0 55.0)",2),
]
cursor.executemany(commandTemplate,data)
```

**How do I get the equivalent functionality with SQLAlchemy core?**

Without the GeomFromText, I think it would look something like this (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25720751/407588)):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam

updateCommand = myTable.update().where(id=bindparam("idToChange"))
data = [
    {'idToChange':1,'Location':"Point(39.0 55.0)"},
    {'idToChange':2,'Location':"Point(39.0 55.0)"},
]
connection.execute(updateCommand,data)
```

I can't just textually replace "Point(39.0 55.0)" with "GeomFromText('Point(39.0 55.0)')", or I get:

```
Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I have found so far involves the use of [text](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) (i.e. constructing [TextClause](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause) objects), which lets you enter SQL syntax (almost) literally.

My example would work something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam
from sqlalchemy import text

updateCommand = myTable.update().where(id=bindparam("idToChange"))
valuesDict = {'idToChange':':idToChange', 
              'Location':text("GeomFromText(:_location)")
}
updateCommand = updateCommand.values(**valuesDict)
data = [
    {'idToChange':1,'_location':"Point(39.0 55.0)"},
    {'idToChange':2,'_location':"Point(39.0 55.0)"},
]
#see the MySQL command as it will be executed (except for data)
print(connection.compile(bind=connection))
#actually execute the statement
connection.execute(updateCommand,data)
```

The key points:

- calling `updateCommand.values` replaces the `VALUES` part of the SQL clause.  Only the columns that you give as kwargs to this call will actually be put into the final `UPDATE` statement
- the values of the keyword arguments to `updateCommand.values` can either be a literal set of data (if you are only updating one row), or it can be a string giving the names of keys in the `data` dictionary that will eventually be passed with the command to the `connection.execute` method.  The format to use is ColumnName=":dictionaryKeyName".
- the values of the keyword arguments can also be the result of a `text` clause, which can itself contain field names in the same ":dictionaryKeyName" format.