# SQL Alchemy update multiple WHERE conditions

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, sql-update

I want to update a column `rtrend` in a MySQL table (`mydata1`) from a `pandas` dataframe (`getdata1`) column `rtrend` making sure the values correspond to the appropriate date (`dt`)

e.g. `rtrend` value for `2016-08-09` from `getdata1` df updates the appropriate MySQL `mydata1` `2016-08-09` `rtrend` value.

In addition specifying a particular security id e.g. `security_id == 'GS'` in this case

```
updateexample = update(mydata1)
      .where(mydata1.c.security_id=='GS', mydata1.c.dt==getdata1['dt'])
      .values(rtrend=getdata1['rtrend'])
```

This produces `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'translate'` Please could someone help with the right way to go about this?

Example of current table and dataframe:

**pandas dataframe 'getdata1'**

```
dt         | security_id | rtrend
2016-08-09 | GS          | 1
2016-08-10 | GS          | -1
```

**MySQL table 'mydata1'**

```
dt         | security_id | rtrend
2016-08-09 | GS          | NULL
2016-08-10 | GS          | NULL
```

Comment: Read about bulk updates; [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25720751/223424). The idea is to `bindparam` the field(s) you want to update, and feed an iterable to the `.execute`. Likely the output of `getdata1` is directly usable. (I hope you just renamed all your objects for the sake of making an example, and use descriptive names in your real code.)

Comment: Thanks Stefano. Yes objects were just renamed for the sake of the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution using the above guidance

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam

```
updatecode1 = update(mydata1).
    where(and_(mydata1.c.dt == bindparam('1dt'), mydata1.c.security_id == bindparam('1security_id')) ).
    values({'rtrend' : bindparam('1rtrend'),'ma200' : bindparam('1ma200')})
```

Then loop to define each value and update table

```
b1 = 'GS'

i = 0

for i in range(len(getdata1)):
    a1 = getdata1.iloc[i]['dt']
    c1 = int(getdata1.iloc[i]['rtrend'])
    d1 = float(getdata1.iloc[i]['MA200'])

    conn.execute(updatecode1, {'1dt' : a1, '1security_id' : b1, '1rtrend' : c1, '1ma200' : d1})
```

I'm sure there is probably a more efficient way than looping in this fashion but this worked for my problem.

NOTE: in 'c1' and 'd1' above I have used int() and float() simply to match data types to my table.