# Doing bulk Update using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a list of dictionaries.

```
 [{'medical_plan_id': 1039481, u'hearing_aids': '', u'clinical_diagnostic_mri': u'20% coinsurance', u'emergency_room': u'20% coinsurance'}, {'medical_plan_id': 1039482, u'hearing_aids': '', u'clinical_diagnostic_mri': u'20% coinsurance', u'emergency_room': u'20% coinsurance'}]
```

I can do bulk insert using below code -

```
def write_plan_benefittodb(self, benefits_dict):
    try:
        count = benefits_dict.__len__()
        engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost/test_db', use_batch_mode=True)
        conn = engine.connect()
        if count > 0:
            print ("Bulk update to database..")
            conn.execute(MedicalPlanBenefit.__table__.insert(), benefits_dict)
        else:
            print("No rows to update..")
        logging.info("Number of rows inserted. %s \n", benefits_dict.__len__())
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        logging.error("No records were updated due to following error . %s", e)
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

I want to run an bulk `Update()`, using my model `MedicalPlanBenefit` on `medical_plan_id`. How to achieve this?

My model class:

```
class MedicalPlanBenefit(Base):
    __tablename__ = "medical_plan_benefits"

    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    medical_plan_id = Column(Integer)
    maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_single = Column(String)
    maximum_out_of_pocket_limit_family = Column(String)
```

I am able to update after hardcoded binding to `values()` . I don't want to do that as the number of columns are in 50s. I want to achieve this with my list of dict somehow.Any suggestions pls.

```
stmt = MedicalPlanBenefit.__table__.update()\
                    .where(MedicalPlanBenefit.__table__.c.medical_plan_id == bindparam('med_plan_id'))\
                    .values({'emergency_room': bindparam('emergency_room')})
                conn.execute(stmt, benefits_dict)
```

Comment: Have you read [Bulk update in SQLAlchemy Core using WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694234/bulk-update-in-sqlalchemy-core-using-where)?

Comment: yes .. I have lots of column to update. Putting each column was not good idea in `values({`. So I was trying if I could put a list of dict over there.

Comment: In the end a "bulk" update ends up using DB-API `executemany()` underneath all the SQLAlchemy layers, and given you are using PostgreSQL and so probably psycopg2, it is essentially as fast as calling `execute()` in a loop.

Comment: On the other hand SQLAlchemy has added support for [`execute_batch()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers). You can enable it by passing `use_batch_mode=True` to `create_engine()`. It might provide some performance benefits.

Comment: @IljaEverilä On using the code which I have updated in my answer . I am getting `InvalidRequestError('This construct does not support multiple parameter sets.',))` error. Could you help me out as to how should I bind my list of dict to my `values`

Comment: Its giving me `StatementError("(sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter '_id'",))` error

Comment: @Ilja .. can you help pls

Comment: The [answer by van](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25720751/2681632) has everything you need. Also read ["Inserts, Updates and Deletes"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#inserts-updates-and-deletes) from the official documentation.

Comment: Tried with the answer in link. I have to hardcoded all my bindings. I dont want to do that. I have updated my question with what I am doing.

Comment: You don't need to. The columns are bound by default using their names. You should be able to simply omit your `values()` call. And that is why you do need to use an alternative bindparam name for parameters used in WHERE clause etc., as you have done.

Comment: Ahhh, finally got my mistakes. Thanks