# How to Update multiple rows in SQLAlchemy? Non ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I update a row in sqlalchemy if the row already contains the same value? I'm not using ORM to be more precise.

I tried with `db.update(table).value(userid=1234, username="Alex")` but every time a single row has the same value I hit the IntegrityError.

Above was just an example an what I'm doing is that I need to update 11 rows and I don't know how I can do that without getting that IntegrityError

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk update in SQLAlchemy Core using WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694234/bulk-update-in-sqlalchemy-core-using-where)

Comment: Nah, I'm updating just the first row unlike the question in the link that is updating multiple rows

Comment: "Above was just an example an what I'm doing is that I need to update 11 rows and I don't know how I can do that without getting that IntegrityError" doesn't sound like what you're describing in your comment. The integrity error is due to your current update statement updating every row's `userid` to 1234 (given `userid` has a unique constraint). Instead you'd limit the rows to update using `update(table).where(table.c.userid == 1234)...`.